# How to compare two elements in an xml file?

Tags: xml, xquery

So i have the following xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE music SYSTEM "music.dtd">
<music>
 <songs>
   <song sid = "s1" time = "2:04" year = "1994">
     <title>Thriller </title>
     <artist>Michael </artist>
       <composers>
          <composer>Michael</composer> 
       </composers>
     <album> Thriller album</album>
    </song>
   <song sid = "s2" time = "2:00" year = "1999">
     <title> Billy </title>
     <artist> Thomas </artist>
     <composers>
       <composer> Rick </composer> 
     </composers>
     <album> The one </album>
    </song>
    <song sid = "s3" time = "1:50" year = "2000">
      <title> Down </title>
      <artist> PJ </artist>
      <composers>
        <composer>Jerry </composer>
      </composers>
      <album>Forty </album>
    </song>
 </songs>
 <playlists>
   <playlist pid = "p1" creator = "Tom">
     <track sid = "s1"/>
   </playlist>
 </playlists>


</music>
```

What I want to do is to get all sid from songs that are NOT in playlists
so in this xml file, I want to have a query return be the sid: s2 and s3 because neither of those two are in playlists and since s1 is in playlists, it should not be returned.

I'm trying to use this query:

```
for $x in doc("music.xml")/music/songs/song/@sid
  return <sid>{data($x)}</sid>
```

I was trying to store the result of that in a variable so i could later compare it to another query which would traverse through playlist but I'm a bit lost on how to even store results of a query into a variable. Any help? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `let` clause to bind variables within a query. Here's an example with several intermediate variables:

```
let $doc := doc("music.xml")/music
let $in-pl := $doc/playlists/playlist/track
let $not-in-pl := $doc/songs/song[fn:not(@sid = $in-pl/@sid)]
for $x in $not-in-pl/@sid
return <sid>{data($x)}</sid>
```

The key expression here is `$doc/songs/song[fn:not(@sid = $in-pl/@sid)]`. This uses the general equality comparison operation `=`, which can compare sequences (0-or-more items). The `fn:not()` function negates the result of the comparison, so this expression selects all `song` elements where `@sid` does not equal the `@sid` attributes of any playlist track.

If you want to store intermediate results across multiple queries, you'll need different approaches depending on your XQuery processor/environment. Some XML databases let you store server/session fields that persist across queries. For others, you'll need to store the intermediate result in a document. What XQuery processor are you using?

**Update**:

There are multiple ways to construct elements in XQuery. You can use element literals, escaping XQuery expressions inside them:

```
return
  <noplaylist>
  {
    for $x in $not-in-pl/@sid
    return
      <sid sid="{ data($x) }"/>
  }
  </noplaylist>
```

or you can use XQuery element/attribute constructors:

```
return
  element noplaylist {
    for $x in $not-in-pl/@sid
    return
      element sid {
        attribute sid { data($x) }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

um..so i tried this:

```
 for $x in doc("music.xml")/music/songs/song/@sid
  where $x != doc("music.xml")//playlists/playlist/track/@sid
  return <sid>{data($x)}</sid>
```

I'm not sure if it's coincidence or not but makes sense now..

Comment: That can work too! If you want to capture the result of that expression in a variable, add `let $results :=` before it, and `return $results` (or some other expression) after it. XQuery is very flexible ;)

Comment: looks like your question got cut off

Comment: How would I return it as <noplaylist> <song sid = "s2"/> <song sid = "s3"/> <noplaylist>

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! I've added some examples of element construction